# RegEx expression maximum 14 digits and maximum 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I'm trying to validate an input in Angular that can only have a maximum of 14 digits and a maximum of 2 decimals (comma separated)

The thing is that Debuggex is validating my expression as correct  but in Angular  doesn't work:

```
^[0-9]{0,14}(,?)[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Angular validator:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{0,14}(,?)[0-9]{1,2}$/)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TJFdC1abG2mg_PAS)

What I need:

```
55555555555555,12 CORRECT (MAXIMUN 14 DIGITS AND MAXIMUM 2 DECIMALS)
55555555555555,1  CORRECT (MAXIMUM14 DIGITS AND 1 DECIMAL)
555555555555555,12 INCORRECT (15 DIGITS AND TWO DECIMALS)
5555555555,        INCORRECT (COMMA WITHOUT DECIMALS)
```

Tanks!

Comment: I tried your regex it's working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvpdsk?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: I checked for given input in stackblitz it's working fine can you check?

Answer (score 0):

#### 14 Characters in length and 2 digits

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="abcd1werty2gnv" id="in" placeholder="enter here"/>
<p id="txt"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function foo() {
  const s = document.getElementById("in").value;
  const regex = /(\d)/g;
  let c = s.match(regex).length;
    let l = s.length;
    document.getElementById("txt").textContent = `length: ${l} digits: ${c}`;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{1,14}(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/)
```

That makes the comma *including* the decimal part optional.